# How do I determine specific BIOS settings with dmidecode and lshw commands with HP servers?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hp-proliant, bios

I am using HP ProLiant Generation 9 servers running Ubuntu as the OS.  I have used dmidecode and lshw commands in the past.  But I don't know how to use them to find all of the BIOS settings.  I support 99.999% uptime SLAs.  So I cannot reboot the servers.  The API interface tool that HP has to find the BIOS settings requires RHEL or Windows as the OS.

The different settings I want to find are obtained by rebooting the server, going into BIOS then doing one of the following:

Setting #1
Go to "System Options" -> "Processor Options" -> see if hyperthreading is enabled.

Setting #2
Go to Server Availability -> see if "ASR Status" is enabled or disabled

How do I use dmidecode or lshw to find the above settings?  I have tried different flags and analyzed hundreds of lines of dmidecode output.

Comment: The two answers combined were perfect.  I think both should get credit.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong tools.
All you'll need are HP's [purpose-built utilities](http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/project/mcp/) for this.

Look for `hpasmcli`:

```
[root@Packed ~]# hpasmcli -s "SHOW HT;SHOW ASR"

Processor hyper-threading is currently enabled.

ASR timeout is 5 minutes.
ASR is currently enabled.
```

---

*other options*

```
 SHOW ASR
 SHOW BOOT
 SHOW DIMM [ SPD ]
 SHOW F1
 SHOW FANS
 SHOW HT
 SHOW IML
 SHOW IPL
 SHOW NAME
 SHOW PORTMAP
 SHOW POWERMETER
 SHOW POWERSUPPLY
 SHOW PXE
 SHOW SERIAL [ BIOS | EMBEDDED | VIRTUAL ]
 SHOW SERVER
 SHOW TEMP
 SHOW TPM
 SHOW UID
 SHOW WOL
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding setting 1: Check the output of `lscpu | grep "Thread(s) per core"`.

Regarding setting 2: Not sure about this, and got no HP server to test. Maybe this is exposed via [IPMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface).

**Edit 1:** Not a solution using `dmidecode` or `lshw`, but if you're fine with installing software from HP: They're providing a repository for rpm and deb based distros. For details have a look [here](http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/project/mcp/).

In short: Add the repository to your sources, via e.g.
`echo deb http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/repo/mcp dist/project_ver non-free >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hp-mcp.list` where `dist/project_ver` is one of:

```
dist             trusty, precise, jessie, squeeze, wheezy
project_ver      current, 9.50, 9.40, 9.25, 9.10
```

After this, run `apt-get update` and `apt-get install hp-health`. This will install `hpasmcli`, which, when called, gives you an interactive prompt. To get the status of asr, run

```
hpasmcli> show asr
```

Comment: If the output of this '"lscpu | grep "Thread(s) per core"' is 2 or more, then hyperthreading is always enabled?

Comment: As far as I know: yes.