# Using hpasmcli, how do I find two specific BIOS settings?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, hp, bios

Using hpasmcli in Ubuntu on an HP ProLiant Generation 9 server, how do I find this BIOS setting?

Boot to BIOS -> System Options -> Virtualization Options is either enabled or disabled

I cannot reboot because I must maintain 99.999% uptime.

I used SHOW SERIAL VIRTUAL.  I used each of these too:

```
     SHOW ASR
     SHOW BOOT
     SHOW DIMM
     SHOW F1
     SHOW FANS
     SHOW HT
     SHOW IML
     SHOW IPL
     SHOW NAME
     SHOW PORTMAP
     SHOW POWERMETER
     SHOW POWERSUPPLY
     SHOW PXE
     SHOW SERVER
     SHOW TEMP
     SHOW TPM
     SHOW UID
     SHOW WOL
```

Will I have to reboot the system to find this setting?  Could dmidecode or lshw help me?

Comment: On any modern Gen9 server, this BIOS setting is enabled by default. Are you experiencing a problem? This is very [similar to your earlier question](https://serverfault.com/questions/733174/how-do-i-determine-specific-bios-settings-with-dmidecode-and-lshw-commands-with).

Answer (score 3):

While this is similar to your [other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/733174/how-do-i-determine-specific-bios-settings-with-dmidecode-and-lshw-commands-with), it would be very nice to understand the full context of what you're doing; e.g. *why are you looking to query BIOS settings, and what does that have to do with the uptime of already-running systems?*

If you're looking at automating the BIOS configuration of multiple HP ProLiant servers, there are also tools for that. The main tool you'll need is `hprcu` from the [SmartStart Scripting Toolkit](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5219389).

This utility can capture or import an XML file containing BIOS configurations. The output file is very readable, so the parameter you're looking for would appear like:

```
  <feature feature_id="158" selected_option_id="1" sys_default_option_id="1" feature_type="option">
    <feature_name>Intel(R) Virtualization Technology</feature_name>
    <option option_id="1">
      <option_name>Enabled</option_name>
    </option>
    <option option_id="2">
      <option_name>Disabled</option_name>
    </option>
  </feature>
```

---

```
Usage: Hprcu [OPTION]
OPTION
  -?, -h    Display this usage message
  -s,       Save the current configuration to a file
  -l        Load configuration settings from a file
  -f        Configuration input/output file, defaults to standard out
  -t        Outputs the feature help and warning text.  Only valid with the Save option.
  -r        Save/Load raw data features(IPL, PCI Devices, Controller Order, etc).  Must be applied to identical systems.
```

Comment: It seems as though the HP Scripting Toolkit is only available for RedHat or SUSE.  I am running Ubuntu.  I cannot reboot the server because I have a 99.999% uptime SLA.  I want to see the current BIOS settings for disaster recovery purposes.

Comment: This is why I don't like running Ubuntu on bare-metal hardware. Sometimes the tools available to more Enterprise distributions aren't compatible or intended for Ubuntu. I don't have a solution for you, though... You may be able to look for `conrep` (the previous tool) and see if you can find an Ubuntu variant.

Answer (score 1):

[dmidecode](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/dmidecode.8.html) should do what you want.  The ROM revision is kept in SMBIOS (aka DMI).  It's a simple string parse at that point to pull the actual version string.